# Spring Boot + Hibernate include hbm.xml from dependency jar

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I'm able to get a sessionfactory bean created like so.

```
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean fact = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
        fact.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return fact;
    }  

    @Autowired
    public HibernateConfig(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

}
```

But using `@ImportResource` or `@EntityScan` with the classpath to the jar or listing the hbm.xml files still yields `not a managed type: class com.opensymphony.workflow.spi.hibernate.HibernateCurrentStep`

I see some answers where you use a different class to generate the sessionFactory bean. Is there an easy way to get the mapping files included in the Entity manager creation?

I was able to scan the hbm.xml files with

```
 @Bean 
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     em.setDataSource(dataSource);
     em.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.bar.domain");

     em.setMappingResources("classpath:x/HibernateCurrentStep.hbm.xml",
    "classpath:x/HibernateHistoryStep.hbm.xml",
    "classpath:x/HibernateWorkflowEntry.hbm.xml");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendor.setShowSql(false);
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);
    return em;
}
```

but then any transaction that uses the session factory gets `No CurrentSessionContext configured!` while basic spring repo methods still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new 
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  em.setDataSource(dataSource);
  em.setPackagesToScan("com.foo.bar.domain");

  em.setMappingResources("com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateCurrentStep.hbm.xml",
     "com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateHistoryStep.hbm.xml",
     "com/opensymphony/workflow/spi/hibernate3/HibernateWorkflowEntry.hbm.xml"); 
  //these needed to be added to have all hibernate config done in one place. 
 em.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, 
      SpringSessionContext.class.getName());
 em.getJpaPropertyMap().put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT,
      PostgreSQL9Dialect.class.getName());

  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  vendor.setShowSql(false);
  em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendor);
  return em;
}
```